# Показать/скрыть часть пунктов списка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Имеется список с n-ным кол-вом пунктов. Как сделать так, чтобы показывались, например, первые 4 пункта, а остальные - по нажатию на кнопку (с возвращением в исходное положение при повторном нажатии), причем с привязкой именно к кол-ву пунктов, а не по заданной высоте.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>First item</li>
</ul>

<a href="#close" class="button">Show</a>
```

UPD: предложенные ниже варианты в целом отвечают на мой вопрос, но я хотел бы использовать для такого списка анимацию. К сожалению, сейчас она работает не совсем корректно (сворачивает/раскрывает по отдельности каждый пункт списка), может есть варианты как этого избежать? [Ссылка](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/RoMEoZ) на пример с анимацией в codepen. Кроме того, мне интересно, почему маркеры пунктов списков после раскрытия `ul` появляются не сразу.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.show-hide-btn').click(function(){
    $('.last-changes-item:nth-child(n+5)').slideToggle('');
  });
});
```

```css
.last-changes-block {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.last-changes-list {
    margin: 0 0 0 17px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.last-changes-list .last-changes-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
.last-changes-list .last-changes-item:nth-of-type(n+5) {
    display: none;
}
.last-changes-list .last-changes-item:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -16px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #333;
}
.last-changes-item .date {
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.show-hide-btn,
.show-hide-btn1 {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 29px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.show-hide-btn:hover,
.show-hide-btn1:hover {
    background: #FBBC25;
    color: #333;
}
.show-hide-btn .fa,
.show-hide-btn1 .fa {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.last-changes-item:nth-child(n+5) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="last-changes-block">
  <ul class="last-changes-list visible-last-changes">
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.24.0</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 21, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.22.1</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 14, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.22.0</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 9, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.20.0</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 6, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.24.0</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 21, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.22.1</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 14, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.22.0</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 9, 2016</span>
    </li>
    <li class="last-changes-item">
      <span class="title">Twitter <strong>v.6.20.0</strong> for Android 4.1</span>
      <span class="date">Nov. 6, 2016</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="show-hide-btn">
    <span>Show more</span>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, без добавления лишней разметки в HTML:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.list-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.u-list').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.u-list li:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.u-list.open li:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="list-toggle">Toggle!</button>
<ul class="u-list">
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант с анимацией

```
var ul = $('.content ul');
var height = $('.content ul').height();
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    if (ul.css('height') == '60px') {
      $(this).text('Hide');
      ul.animate({height: height + "px"}, 300);
    } else {
      $(this).text('Show');
      ul.animate({height: "60px"}, 300);
    }
  })
```

и `style="overflow: hidden;"` для элемента `<ul>`

https://jsfiddle.net/j7ahj2f1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('.toggle').toggle();
})
```

```css
.toggle{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li class="toggle">Fifth item</li>
  <li class="toggle">First item</li>
  <li class="toggle">First item</li>
</ul>

<a href="#close" class="button">Show</a>
```

Будут прятаться все с классом который укажете.

Answer (score 1):

Решение без модификации *разметки*, *css*, только  средствами *jQuery*, с вариативным(изменяемым) шагом вывода, проверено:

```
var i = 0;
var object = '.content ul li'; //Искомый объект, класс 'content' настраиваете под свой/убираете
var count = $(object).length; //Кол-во искомых объектов
$('.button').off('click'); //Отбиндим предыдущие функции(опционально)
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    if(i >= count){
        $(object).show();
        i = 0;
        return false; //выйдем из функции, при ее сбросе
    }
    var delimiter = i + 4; //вычислим индекс следующего "последнего элемента"
    $(object).hide(); //спрячем все объекты
    while(i < delimiter){
        $(object).eq(i).show();//покажем только нужные
    }
})
$('.button').trigger('click');//"Костыль", если нужно по умолчанию сначала выводить только первые 4 записи.
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я плохо разбираюсь в jquery/js, но в кодпен Ваш вариант, к сожалению, не работает - в скрипте находит бесконечный цикл

http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/MbVjxK?editors=1010

Comment: @Игорь, да, при попытке внесения фикса, случайно поломал; вот
рабочий [pencode](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbVbQm?editors=1010)